# Disabled MD5 and enabled SHA under SCHANNEL/Hashes in registry. xfreerdp fails with an ssl i/o error

Tags: authentication, hash, sha, md5, rdp

So delving into securing server and not quite understanding how I broke the ability to rdp into my server (using xfreerdp). I disabled MD5 as an available hash and enabled SHA. The exact changes in the registry I made were to:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5
  Disabled this.
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA
  Enabled this.
```

I am not finding any information on exactly how xfreerdp handles authentication (but guessing it aligns to rdp), which tells me it uses NLA (authenticates prior to passing the full rdp session). I have been scrounging online but cannot determine why xfreerdp is failing to authenticate once I force the server to only allow SHA hashing algorithms (unless it just simply only supports MD5? Searching online i see references to SHA but cannot find a definitive answer). Any thoughts on why disabling MD5 on the server is breaking xfreerdp connections?

Comment: Is there any distinct error message you can provide, possibly from some verbose logging?

Comment: I am unable to find a way to enable verbose or debug with xfreerdp (1.0.2). Sorry! The error that gets returned at the command line just states "SSL I/O Error".

Comment: https://www.hardening-consulting.com/en/posts/20193001-freerdp-and-wlog.html has some information about enabling and collecting logs in FreeRDP, including xfreerdp. It's odd that the manpage lacks it...

Comment: TLS 1.1 and below use both MD5 and SHA1 in a critical security feature. Perhaps for some reason your SSL connection is using TLS v1.1 or older.

Comment: @CBHacking Thanks for the link. I setup the variables but nothing was logged. I am wondering if the version I am running is just old (its from 2013 compared to that site which was written in 2019)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Decent thought, I am running an older version of xfreerdp. I cannot determine what algorithms this version supports but it could be the issue

Comment: @IT_User Why are you running an older version?

Comment: Its what was on there prior. I want to upgrade but not sure if this is even the underlying issue and trying to understand why/what is causing the breakage.

Comment: At this point based on the comments ima go with its that xfreerdp is outdated and potentially doesn't support the algorithms I am enforcing. When I can upgrade I will update this with the results.